# No module named 'PyEmu

Tags: python, python-3.x

No module named PyEmu

PIP:
C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\New folder>pip install pyemu
Requirement already satisfied: pyemu in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (1.2.0)

Installed pyemu still showed this error

Comment: you have more than one version of python installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to work in a virtual environment. So you can know the problem and work in a more orderly way.

You can **create a virtual environment** in Windows with `virtualenv`:

```
virtualenv envname -p python3
```

Then you must **activate it**:

```
envname\Scripts\activate
```

Then, **install your packages** in isolation. If you're still getting errors, you may need to install older versions of the package (and update this issue with your code).